# Data migration: "Init vector must be a string of 16 bytes" due to old weakly encrypted data in the database - what to do?

Tags: database, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, encryption-key

I'm migrating a Magento 1 store to Magento 2.3.4 and I'm encountering an error at the data migration "Map Step".

```
In Mcrypt.php line 81:

  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Init vector must be a string of 16 bytes.
```

I've put my old M1 crypt_key into the config.xml file as usual - but that isn't the problem.

The problem is I have very old, weakly-encrypted data in my M1 database which apparently cannot be decrypted by M2.

`Magento/Framework/Encryption/Adapter/Mcrypt.php` line 81 checks that the correct `$initVectorSize` for the selected encryption cipher is used. In this case it expects a length of 16 bytes because it's trying to use the old `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` cipher (see `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/Encrypt.php` line 73). I assume this is what "old" Magento 1 data was encrypted with.

Hoever, I have data in my M1 database which is apparently even older. It seems to have been encrypted with an even older/weaker cipher with an init vector length of just 8 bytes (i.e. not MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) and therefore the migration tool cannot decrypt it.

The data seems to be `cc_number_enc` from the `sales_flat_order_payment` table although I suppose there could be other similar data in the database elsewhere.

What should I do in this case? Should I just delete the data from the database and continue the migration? Or is there a better workaround?